# I cant close dropdown menu in header

Tags: dropdown, bootstrap-5

used html, css bootstrap in my project. I couldnt close dropdown menu. How can I do that ? if I should javascript code, how can write it ?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lAZQQ.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WWX3a.png)